# OpenMP Profiler (ompP) fails when declaring locks using runtime routine - omp_set_lock(&lock)

Tags: multithreading, profiling, openmp

I am trying to measure lock contention in my openMP program. I have been using OpenMP Profiler (ompP) for this purpose. ompP works perfectly fine for code where all the parallelization is expressed using compiler directives. However, the profiler seems to fail when the code uses the runtime routine omp_set_lock()

The error message I am getting is this:

```
*** 12 
*** 12 driverForGraphClustering: ompp_regstat.c:870: void regstat_on_enter(regstat_t*, ompp_reg_type_t, unsigned int, int): Assertion `0' failed.
*** 12 Aborted (core dumped)
```

On running the program with gdb, I found that the error was triggered right after the omp_set_lock() command. Further, if I set the environment variable

```
export OMPP_DISABLE_LOCKS=yes
```

then I dont get any error.

I also checked the file ompp_regstat.c at line number 870. The code is essentially switch statement that is designed to fail if the parallelization is not via a compiler directive.

This leads me to ask two questions:

1. How do I detect lock contention for locks defined by runtime routines? ompP does not seem to be capable of doing this or am I missing an obvious step?
2. What is the meaning of the synchronization overhead in the report generated by ompP? Does this include contention for locks that are defines implicitly via pragmas?